# Rephotography (or matching two photos)

Tags: python, opencv

According to Wikipedia:

> Rephotography is the act of repeat photography of the same site, with a time lag between the two images; a "then and now" view of a particular area.

I have some old and new photos of the same building.

Can I automatically (using OpenCV perhaps) match photos, so as to overlap the edges of the buildings?

I have no working code. I have no code at all. Just asking if using Python and OpenCV is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [Image registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration).

To make what you want to do with OpenCV and Python, I would advise you to follow this [tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/). The basic principles are quite well explained and the source code is published alongside the article.

If you want to do this automatically, the points used to compute the homography matrix can be computed thanks to one of many Features Detection / Features Matching algorithms provided by the OpenCV library. 
In your case, that is with photographs of a building, finding and matching good features shouldn't be a major problem.